# Epigraph form of an optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Why is the optimization problem

$\textrm{minimize} ~f_0(x)$

equivalent to

$\textrm{minimize} ~~t \\ s.t. ~~ f_0(x)\leq t$

but not equivalent to the following?

$\textrm{minimize} ~~t \\ s.t. ~~ t=f_0(x)$

I found this example in Boyd's book and although he doesn't deny that the first and third minimization problems could be equivalent, it doesn't explicitly say so either? I'm wondering why he's using an inequality instead of an equality as a constraint?

Comment: Of course the equality version is equivalent. I guess the point of the inequality version is that you can more easily get a starting point for one of the various successive improvement methods. If you insist on equality, you're not giving those methods much of a chance to play.

Comment: On reflection, there's really no advantage, either way.  So perhaps, just author's choice.

Comment: @quasi There is an important advantage in the case when $f_0$ is convex, because then the epigraph form problem is a convex optimization problem, whereas the equality constrained version is a nonconvex problem.

Comment: I follow -- for the convex case, the inequality version yields a region of the form required by the standard methods.

Comment: @littleO Why do you say that the equality constrained version is nonconvex? Only because the equality could be non-affine? or is there another reason?

Comment: Just my two cents: the epigraph form is equivalent to the original problem provided that $f_0$ is lower semicontinuous. These equivalences are explained nicely in the book *Optimization Models* by G. Calafiore and L. El Ghaoui, Cambridge University Press [Section 8.3.4]

Comment: Agree with @littleO, when $f_0$ is not affine, the problem stated in the third approach may not be a convex problem, where equality constraint functions are required to be affine; however, the problem stated in the second approach is still a standard convex problem, as we only require inequality constant functions to be convex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose the original **standard form** of an optimization problem is:

$$\min~~f_0(\mathbf{x})\\ \text{s.t. } ~f_i(\mathbf{x}) \leq 0, i=1,...,m \\~~~~~~~ h_j(\mathbf{x}) = 0, j=1,...,p $$

in which  $f_i$ for  $i=1,...,m$ are inequality constraint functions and $h_j$ for $j=1,...,p$ are equality constraint functions. For a **convex** optimization problem, $f_0(\mathbf{x})$ and $f_i$ for $i=1,...,m$  are **convex** functions and $h_j$ for $j=1,...,p$ are **affine** functions.

Now, for the *equivalent* epigraph representation of the original problem in standard form, we use the corresponding constraint in **inequality** form, we have:
$$\min ~~t \\ \text{s.t.} ~~ f_0(\mathbf{x}) - t\leq 0 \\ \qquad f_i(\mathbf{x}) \leq 0, i=1,...,m \\~~~~~~~ h_j(\mathbf{x}) = 0, j=1,...,p.$$ 
Assume the original problem is a *convex* optimization problem. To provide the original problem in epigraph standard representation, but **preserving** the problem to be in convex form, it needs to add an inequality constraint function $f_0(\mathbf{x}) - t$ which is convex in $(\mathbf{x},t)$; this inequality corresponds to the $\mathbf{epi} ~f_0$, here, is a *convex set*. So, the problem in the equivalent epigraph representation is still in a *standard convex optimization problem form*. Furthermore, for *straightforward and meaningful analysis* of a problem, also designing an efficient algorithm, different equivalent representation of a problem can be used.

Note: $f$ is convex if and only if $\textbf{epi} ~f$ is convex set.

Comment: No need for all the bold face here but good answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelGrant for your notice; I just applied your comment as much as possible. :)

Comment: @stephen Why is there an inequality sign for your equality constraints $h_j(x)$?

Comment: That was a typo; thanks @Teodorism for your notice, corrected.

Comment: @Stephen Please, correct me if I'm wrong. You're basically saying because in the definition of the standard form (of a convex optimization problem), we only allow affine equalities, we use $f_0(x)−t\leq 0$ instead of $f_0(x)−t=0$? Otherwise, if we'd lifted the 'affineness' requirement from the definition, we could've used $f_0(x)−t=0$?

Comment: I recommend you to carefully read the whole answer; just one point is to convert it to the equivalent epigraph representation; so, the constraint is convex set iff the function is convex. How can you call that is equivalent *epigraph* representation, without inequality?

Comment: @Stephen So, the only reason why they use inequality is because they want it in epigraph form? What is the significance of converting the problem in this form instead of just adding an equality constraint?

Comment: @Teodorism: in your question, you asked about why the inequality (form) is used; so, in my answer, I told why. Now, you ask why epigraph representation, so please refer to the last two sentence of the answer; if you have more experience in problem analysis and derivation of some closed form solution, then you will find this representation very meaningful.